# Many to many ordered by count of relationship (Entity Framework, Linq)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have a table structure like this...

[image]

When I import this into entity framework it looks like this...

[image]

What I need to do is build a query from LINQ that will return a list of every unique store, populated with a list of people who like that store. (easy, right?)

THE CATCH:
I need to filter the list to the person's list of friends that get passed in as a List to the linq query (comes from facebook, so relationships are not in db)...

ONE MORE THING:
i need to return if the store is a favorite of the person requesting the data (the `uid` as shown below)

OK, ANOTHER THING:
I need to return the list sorted by the highest number of friends who like an item to lowest (the ui below is wrong in that regard)

Here is the method signature of the linq query i need

```
public List<Store> GetTopStoresFilteredByFriends
          (int uid, List<int> friends, int size = 10){

}
```

To return a user interface that looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Do the list of friends have counterpart "Person" entries in your db?

Comment: yes, they are people in the PERSON table, its a self-referencing relationship, but the relationship lives with facebook

Comment: that is the person requesting the data, so you can populate the "Like" property of the data result (see above) also, i added a clarification in the post about this

Answer (score 2):

This query gives you a list of every unique store, populated with a list of people who like that store which is also liked by at least one of the friends in the list that you are passing order by the highest number of friends that like the store plus a flag to show whether or not each store is liked by the person who requested the data:

```
var query = (from s in ctx.Stores.Include("People")
             from p in s.People
             let n = friends.Sum(f => s.People.Count(item => item.PersonID == f))
             where friends.Any(f => f == p.PersonID)
             select new {
                 TheStore = s,
                 IsFavorite = s.People.Any(ppl => ppl.PersonID == uid),
                 N = n
             })
             .Distinct()
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.N);
```

Comment: how would you do the sorting by the highest number of friends that like the store?

Comment: is that let n = s.People.Count the total number of people or just the friends?

Comment: one little glitch that is showing up with your query is that if there are 2 friends then the item shows up 2 times in the results... not sure exactly why

Comment: and yes, the list is sorted by the total number of people who like the store, not the friends only.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I've corrected it. This one definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

var stores = new Dictionary();

//one entry for each store, starting with count = 0

stores.Add(1, 0);

stores.Add(2, 0);

stores.Add(3, 0);

var peopleWithFriends = new Dictionary < int, List < Person > > ();

//one entry for each person containing the list of friends
var person0 = new Person();
person0.Id = 0;

var person1 = new Person();
person1.Id = 1;

var person2 = new Person();
person2.Id = 2;

peopleWithFriends.Add(0, new List < Person > {person1, person2});
peopleWithFriends.Add(1, new List < Person > { person0, person2 });
peopleWithFriends.Add(2, new List< Person > { person0, person1});

foreach (var store in
 peopleWithFriends.Keys.Select(personId => peopleWithFriends[personId])
  .SelectMany(friends => Enumerable.SelectMany(friends, friend => friend.Stores)))
{
 stores[store.Id]++;
}

now you can sort the stores dictionary by the highest count, and return the result